# Putting array_filter() in a function

Tags: php, function, array-filter

I would like to transform the code below in a function

```
function filter($row){return ($row['id_menu'] == 10);}

$matches = array_filter($array_mostrar_privilegios, "filter");
foreach ($matches as $element)
{
    echo $element['consultar'];
}
```

like

```
function filter($row, $num)
{
    return ($row['id_menu'] == $num);
}
function find($my_array, $num)
{
    $matches = array_filter($my_array, "filter($row, $num)");
    foreach ($matches as $element)
    {
        return $element['consultar'];
    }
}
```

but i don't how to make it work

Comment: `filter` doesn't call `find`, and `find` doesn't call `filter`. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @hd.: The 2nd parameter to `array_filter` is a callback.  He wants to call `filter` with an extra parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.3+, then there is no need to use a string as the callback parameter.  PHP 5.3+ has anonymous functions.

```
$matches = array_filter($my_array, function($row) use($num){
    return filter($row, $num);
});
```

If you do not have PHP 5.3, then you can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function) (***warning***: this uses `eval()`):

```
$matches = array_filter($my_array, create_function('$row', 'return filter($row,'.$num.');'));
```

Comment: it returns the follow error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION"

Comment: That means you have PHP 5.2 or below.

Comment: @user3249927: Your options are (in the order of preference): 1) Upgrade to a more recent PHP version, 2) Define the function outside (as you're currently doing), 3) Use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/create_function).

Comment: @user3249927: Try the 2nd example I've added to the answer.  I would consider upgrading PHP, but if you can't then `create_function` should work.

Comment: I'will try to update later and try your first option before. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

Using closures:

```
function find($my_array, $num)
{
    $matches = array_filter(
        $my_array, 
        function filter($row) use($num) {
            return ($row['id_menu'] == $num);
        }
    );
    foreach ($matches as $element)
    {
        return $element['consultar'];
    }
}
```

except that your return inside the foreach will only return the first element from $matches

If you expect multiple $matches values, and want to return them all, consider using yield to turn this into a generator

Comment: i had to remove the "filter" to work.. and it return a error to me "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION"

Comment: @user3249927: If you only need the first result, why do you need a loop? Just print the first result: `$matches[0]['consultar']`.

Comment: i really need like this, coz i have a lot of lines on this array. Thanks for helping